# Best way to print rows not common to two large files in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have two files which are of following format.
**File1:** - It contains 4 column. First field is ID in text format and rest of columns are also some text values.

```
id1 val12 val13 val14
id2 val22 val23 val24
id3 val32 val33 val34
```

**File2** - In file two I only have IDs.

```
id1
id2
```

**Output**

> ```
> id3 val32 val33 val34
> ```

My question is: How to find rows from first file whose ID(first field) does not appear in second file. Size of both files in pretty large with file1 containing 42 million rows, size 8GB and file2 contains 33 million IDs. Order of IDs in two files might not be same.

Comment: with this much data, you'll most likely get better performance stuffing it into a database and writing SQL.

Comment: well i prefer join.but you can use awk as well:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this with awk:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { h[$1] = 1; next } !h[$1]' file2 file1
```

The first block gathers ids from `file2` into the `h` hash. The last part (`!h[$1]`) executes the default block (`{ print $0 }`) if the id wasn't present in `file2`.

Comment: Note this requires the entirety of File2 to be held in memory.

Comment: @glennjackman: indeed, and this will be the case for any solution where `file1` and `file2` are not sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the two files are sorted by id, then something like

```
join "-t " -j 1 -v 1 file1 file2
```

should do it.

Comment: +1 nice. You don't need `-t" "` and `-j1`, these are defaults.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't remember the default for -t.

Comment: Files are not sorted. I once tried sorting file1 on it but it was taking a long amout of time. Length of ID is really big. Its around 150 character long md5sum.

Comment: In which case, I'd look at Thor's solution (only because I think the RAM use will be lower).   Keep in mind though that the other solutions will load file2 into RAM.  150*33000000 is around 5GB raw I think.  Better have a decent machine.

Comment: @Jitendra: sorting can be done in stages with the `-m` switch and parallelized, see for example [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__processing_a_big_file_using_more_cores) GNU parallel example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't claim that this is the "best" way to do it because best can include a number of trade-off criteria, but here's one way:

You can do this with the `-f` option to specify `File2` as the file containing search patterns to `grep`:

```
grep -v -f File2 File1 > output
```

And as @glennjackman suggests:

> One way to force the id to match at the beginning of the line:`grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/' File2) File1`

Comment: This might fail, when some id from `File2` appears as value in `File1`.

Comment: That won't be the case. Ids won't appear as values.

Comment: he would need -v option as he doesn't want lines from File2 in File1

Comment: One way to force the id to match at the beginning of the line: `grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/' File2) File1`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks! I thought about it and couldn't come up with an elegant way of doing it - this is perfect

Comment: This approach failed. When I ran command, It errored out printing some memory related information. Solution given by Thor worked. Thanks all.